# how to prevent promise getting called on page load

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am new to the concept of promise in JavaScript. I have tried to implement promise in my but don't know why it is getting on page load. I know this not a tutorial website but any help would help me to improve my concept of promise. I tried to google the solution for my problem but I was not able to find the solution. As per my logic SearchRecord function should be called on button click but it is getting called on page load

```
 <button id="Query" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="SearchRecord()" value="Search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>
function SearchRecord() {         
    let InvOrg = $('#InvOrg').val();
    let ItemCode = $('#ItemCode').val();
    let Description = $('#Description').val();

     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GINV/GINV01/tableData',
            type: 'GET',
            async:'true',
            data: {
                InvOrg: InvOrg, ItemCode: ItemCode, Description: Description
            },
            success: function (data) {
                resolve(data)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            },
        })
     })
              
}
SearchRecord()
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        tabledata(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
function tabledata(data) {
    debugger;
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#MainTable')) {
        $('#MainTable').DataTable().destroy();
    }
    $('#MainTable tbody').empty();

    var table = $('#MainTable').DataTable({
        data: data.listIndexData,
        stateSave: true,
        "columns": [
          
            { "data": "itemCode"  },

            { "data": "itemDescription" },

            { "data": "uom" },

            { "data": "quantity", "className": "text-right" },

            { "data": "pslRate", "className": "text-right"  },

            { "data": "value", "className": "text-right" },

            { "data": "unit" },

        ],
    });
   

}
```

Comment: Remove the `()` like this: `onclick="SearchRecord"`. Also you probably need an event handler function there. You are actually calling the SearchRecord on load. This has nothing to do with promises. rather event handlers.

Comment: *`SearchRecord().then((data) => { console.log(data); tabledata(data) }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) })`* <= the call is right there. Did you want to put all of that in your click handler?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie No, `onclick="SearchRecord()"` is fine to call the function when the element is clicked. `onclick="SearchRecord"` does not work. Maybe you thought of `document.getElementById("Query").onclick = SearchRecord;` (where parenthesis wouldn't work)?

Comment: @Bergi I want to call the SearchRecord function on button click, not on page load

Comment: @vwadhwa3 yes, then don't do that. Also it's unclear when/how you want to call the `tabledata` function.

Comment: @bergi I want to call the SearchRecord function on button click and tabledata function when the promise get resolved

Comment: @vwadhwa3 yes, then write the entire `SearchRecord().then(tabledata)` code inside the event handler

Comment: @Bergi you want me to do this <button id="Query" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="SearchRecord().then(tabledata)" value="Search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>

Comment: @vwadhwa3 Yes, that would work, or what Abdulla did in his answer below. (Also keep the `.catch(…)` error handling, I only omitted that for conciseness)

Comment: @Bergi I am grateful for your support and help. I really need to learn more about this concept. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're invoking the SearchRecord function.

```js
SearchRecord()
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        tabledata(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

The above code should be contained in another function.

```html
 <button id="Query" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="anotherFunction()" value="Search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>

function anotherFunction(){
  SearchRecord()
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        tabledata(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to this question with the help of Bergi although Abdulla's answer is also right. I wanted to this without making a new function.

so per the suggestion of Bergi Answer to this question is

```
 <button id="Query" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="SearchRecord().then(tabledata).catch((error) => { console.log(error) })" value="Search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search</button>
```

Comment: This makes the code too ugly, less readable and more prone to errora. Consirder wrapping it in another function as better choice.